# Why is my custom view not printing something inside this onTapGesture?

Tags: swiftui

HomeView

```
import SwiftUI



struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var mapState = MapViewState.noInput
    @EnvironmentObject var locationViewModel: LocationSearchViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var launchScreenManager : LaunchScreenManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                UberMapViewRepresentable(mapState: $mapState    )
                
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                if mapState == .searchingForLocation{
                    LocationSearchView(mapState: $mapState)
                } else if mapState == .noInput {
                    LocationSearchActivationView()
                        .padding(.top, 72)
                        .onTapGesture{
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                mapState = .searchingForLocation
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                MapViewActionButton(mapState: $mapState)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.top, 4)
                    .onTapGesture{
                        print("Why isn't this printing?")
                    }
            }
            
            if mapState == .locationSelected || mapState == .polylineAdded{
                RideRequestView()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .onReceive(LocationManager.shared.$userLocation) { location in
            if let location = location {
                locationViewModel.userLocation = location
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            DispatchQueue
                .main
                .asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    launchScreenManager.dismiss()
                }
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

MapViewActionButton

```
import SwiftUI

struct MapViewActionButton: View {
    @Binding var mapState: MapViewState
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : LocationSearchViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                actionForState(mapState)
            }
            
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: imageNameForState(mapState))
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
                .background(.white)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 6)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
    
    func actionForState(_ state: MapViewState) {
        switch state {
        case .noInput:
            print("no input")
        case .searchingForLocation:
            mapState = .noInput
        case .locationSelected, .polylineAdded:
            mapState = .noInput
            viewModel.selectedUberLocation = nil
            
        }
    }
    
    func imageNameForState(_ state: MapViewState) -> String {
        switch state {
        case .noInput:
            return "line.3.horizontal"
        case .searchingForLocation, .locationSelected, .polylineAdded:
            return "arrow.left"
       
            
        }
    }
}

struct MapViewActionButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapViewActionButton(mapState: .constant(.noInput))
    }
}
```

I understand that maybe not all this code is relevant but basically when I am adding an onTapGesture to MapViewActionButton and printing something, it doesn't print? Does anybody know why this can be happening?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmgFT.png)

If I add a background(.red) modifier to my MapViewActionButton it seems it's not going over just the button(presumably because I am setting the frame width to infinity but how come it's not when I tap the image itself it's not detecting the tap gesture?

I tried playing around with this a lot but I couldn't really figure out why this was happening.

Answer (score 2):

By using this you can use print anywhere in code. If there is no other issue.

```
let _ = print("Why isn't this printing?")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Button("Button") {
    print("tapped")
}
.onTapGesture{
       print("Why isn't this printing?")
                 }
}
```